# Bind a DataGrid to an ObservableCollection<T> in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datacontext

How can I bind a `Datagrid` with two columns (`DataGridTextColumn` and `DataGridComboBoxColumn`) to an `ObservableCollection<Team> Teams`?

The `DataGridTextColumn` is bound correctly. But nothing is displayed in `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

***Code-behind***

```
   public class Team
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<string> Members { get; set; }
   }

   public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private ObservableCollection<Team> teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>
      {
         new Team()
         {
            Name = "A", Members = new List<string> {"John", "Jack"},
         },
         new Team()
         {
            Name = "B", Members = new List<string> {"Sarah", "Anna"},
         }
      };
      public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams
      {
         get { return teams; }
         set
         {
            teams = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Teams");
         }
      }

      private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         var handler = PropertyChanged;
         if (handler == null) return;

         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }
```

***XAML***

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Teams}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Team" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Members" 
                                        Width="*"
                                        />

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do you have the DataContext of the view set?  Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: @StephenWilson Yes, I have set that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use "DataGridTemplateColumn".
Dont forget to add a selectedItem Member.

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Members">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="wpfApplication1:Team">
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Members}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks Rom, can you tell me how to add a selectedItem binding. I just want to display the first index.

Comment: 1. Add selected property :    public class Team
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SelectedMember { get; set; }
        public List<string> Members { get; set; }
    } 2. Name = "A", Members = new List<string> {"John", "Jack"},SelectedMember = "John"  3. <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMember}"/>

Answer (score 1):

Your need to setup `DataContext` property of your control with instance of ViewModel. Like, in control constructor

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

and fill DisplayMemberPath in your XAML

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Team" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ...
```

**UPDATE**

I was inccorrect. Because `DataGridComboboxColumn` does not inherit DataContext, to do what you want you have to do in following way:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Teams}"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Team" 
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Width="*"
                                 Binding="{Binding Name}" />

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Members" 
                                    Width="*"
                                    >

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Members}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Members}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you help me with DisplayMemberPath ?

Comment: Still doesn't work! Only the DataGridTextColumn is displayed! I'm having problem with the DataGridComboBoxColumn.

Comment: @Vahid Updated answer

Comment: Thanks actually I have came up with this answer searching. the Combox is filled now but how to display a selected index. I want to show the first element by default!

Comment: If you want to use SelectedIndex or SelectedItem, you should add it in your viewmodel and initialize inside view model, then bind to Column.